# How to automatically adjust height/width on PDF export

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Following the documentation, that's what I've tried so far:

```
<kendo-grid-pdf fileName="{{lbl_FundsGridPdfFile}}" [allPages]="true" paperSize="A4" [repeatHeaders]="true" [landscape]="true">
            <kendo-grid-pdf-margin top="2cm" left="1cm" right="1cm" bottom="2cm"></kendo-grid-pdf-margin>
            <ng-template kendoGridPDFTemplate let-pageNum="pageNum" let-totalPages="totalPages">
                 <div class="page-template">
                     <div class="header">
                     <div class="rightFloat">Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}</div>
                             Multi-page grid with automatic page breaking
                     </div>
                     <div class="footer">
                             Page {{ pageNum }} of {{ totalPages }}
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-pdf>
```

The pdf result is:

[image: Pdf]

How can the height/width be adjusted in order not to miss any useful info?

Answer (score 0):

@Giannis, You can set appropriate width to kendo-grid-column, So that it never miss any value of that column itself while exporting that grid.

`<kendo-grid-column field="NameofColumn" title="Name" width="250">
  </kendo-grid-column>`

For trial you can check with [this link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/pdf-export/)

Comment: Setting a specific width for columns is not a solution in my case. Also, the link is not working...